# Связывание переменных и оператор IN

Tags: oracle, производительность, sql

Доброе время суток, коллеги!

Несомненно, связывание переменных важный момент при написании адекватного приложения, работающего с БД. Но как быть с оператором **IN** ?

Попробовали передать строку вот так:

```
select * from table where id in ( :array_id )
:array_id = '10,20,30,40,50'
```

Естественно *array_id* воспринимается как строка и нужного эффекта не производит...

Далее пришла в голову идея о использовании

```
select * from table where
instr( :array_id , ','||id||',') > 0
:array_id = ',10,20,30,40,50,'
```

Но подсознание подсказывает что это будет не самое лучшее решение с точки зрения быстродействия.

Неужели нет более корректного решения подобной проблемы?

Comment: Что мешает в цикле формировать параметры по одному?

Comment: Потенциальное быстродействие.
Достаточно большой запрос (порядка сотен кб чистого текста) выполняется соответственно очень долго. идея была в уходе от hard parse данного запроса.

Comment: Без кавычек пробовали?

Comment: пробовали по всякому. кавычки тут лишь для обозначения начала и конца строки не более того.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

варианты решения:

1) из строки `"1,2,3"` формируем запрос вида:

```
select 1 as <fieldname> from dual
union
select 2 as <fieldname> from dual
union
select 3 as <fieldname> from dual
```

который подставляется в изначальный запрос. если не прокатит то придется еще и завернуть в курсор + стоит вынести локигу в отдельную функцию/процедуру

2) используем временную таблицу. если нет таблицы создаем ее:

```
create tmp_table as (
... вставляем сюда запрос из пункта 1
)
```

если есть таблица (спец. заготовленная для наших нужд) то все проще (формируем набор insert'ов):

```
insert into tmp_table values (1);
insert into tmp_table values (2);
insert into tmp_table values (3);
```

думаю что делать дальше с ними понятно ?

---

В свое время аналогичную задачу решали таким способом: 2 таблицы tasks, task_args. в первой задаем таск во второй его аргументы. Процедура вытягивала по id задачи значения парметров. напр:

```
select int_value from task_args where task_id = ? and arg_name = "account_id";

select str_value from task_args where task_id = ? and arg_name = "account_name";
```

не стоит забывать что любые подобные извращения убивают перфоманс

Comment: На данный момент придерживаемся именно этого варианта. А насчет перфоманса - немного дольше будет выполняться запрос только в первый раз, а потом уже всё пойдет как по маслу для целой серии таких запросов, так как текст запроса будет идентичный и успешно достанется из кэша

Comment: я описал 2 варианта (а если быть точным 3: dynamic query/user temp table/use regular table). напишите плз какой конкретно вы выбрали, интересно :)

Answer (score 1):

[Обсуждение на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091777/delphi-how-to-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-sql-query) для примера. Краткий ответ: так не получится.
Варианты решения:

1. генерация текста запроса и параметры в цикле.
2. создание временной таблицы и занесение списка в нее, т.е. парсить строку будет субд.
3. instr - убивает всю идею индексов и проч.

Самый простой и правильный метод - первый. Какой бы ни был запрос, проще его сформировать и дать базе заниматься тем, что она умеет лучше - выбирать данные, а строки передавать для парсинга - это вариант тупиковый.

Comment: еще раз объясняю запросы сформированные вашим методом для различных наборов данных будут *различны*, что не позволит мне при повторном вызове данного запроса но с другим набором данных избежать хард парса

Comment: @Grizli Я как бы с первого раза понял. Еще раз говорю без изменения запроса не получится передать список параметров. Составьте запросы на 2,3,..100 параметров, берите тот, который в данный момент подходит. Кэшируйте запросы. Или используйте шаблоны для подстановки этих списков.  
Поймите, вам кажется, что вы передаете список int'ов. А драйвер соединения с базой этого наперед не знает, а вдруг там у вас буква проскочит, а вдруг это вы строки решили списком передавать, а вдруг в одной из строк будет запятая. Драйвер ждет от вас для каждого параметра еще и тип, а для некоторых типов еще и длину.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за ссылку, будем рыть в сторону второго варианта.

*Какой бы ни был запрос, проще его сформировать и дать базе заниматься тем, что она умеет лучше - выбирать данные* - Не всегда так. когда запрос парсится только более 30 минут, волей неволей задумаешься о других вариантах

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не нова. Есть [хорошая статья](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) на эту тему. 
Помнится, что есть перевод какой-то версии этой статьи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать DBMS.SQL